# How do I correctly setup a publisher tag on my pages?

Tags: android, html, css

I want to connect my website up to it's Google page to add a bit of authority in the search rankings and at the minute I have the following publisher tag

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxx" rel="publisher">
```

Now the tag points to my profile page on Google but however the site also has a Google+ Page dedicated to the site. I am wondering if I should be pointing the link tag to my profile page or to my Google+ page, does anyone know what route is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1708844) themselves:

> If you’ve created a Google+ page, we strongly recommend linking from
>   that page to your website and vice versa. Linking your Google+ page
>   and your site like this not only helps you build relationships with
>   friends and followers, but also gives Google information we can use to
>   determine the relevancy of your site to a user query in Google Web
>   Search.

Comment: I have connected the publisher tag directly to my Google+ page and tested it. It seems to work and Google has picked up on it.